# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '595.92

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here is my code:

```
x = '595.92'
print int(x)
```

When I run it, i have the following error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '595.92'
```

How can I fix that?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want it to be? It's not an `int`.

Answer (score 6):

Make it a `float` first:

```
>>> int(float('595.92')) # float('595.92') == 595.92
595
```

Comment: @MichaelVayvala but it's not.

Comment: @MichaelVayvala You can't return that as an *integer*. You can return it as a *float* instead

Comment: or better, a `Decimal`.

Comment: From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer) An integer is a number that can be written without a fractional or decimal component

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to convert a hard coded string that looks like a float to an int?

```
x = '596'
print int(x)
```